# How to get Asus XG-C100C 10G ethernet card working on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet, netplan

Is there anything you need to do to get this network card working in 18.04? It was working fine in 16.04 with the “atlantic” driver built from sources provided by Asus. After upgrading to 18.04, I can see that driver now seems to be included in Ubuntu, and I can see the card using `lshw  -class network`, but syslog shows the ethernet link is down.

There were bigger issues with networking. It wouldn’t work with the built in gigabit ethernet port either. I had to setup netplan to get that working. However, for the 10G card, running “networkctl” it shows “no-carrier” / “configuring” for this interface, even if the ethernet cable is connected.

So I'm not sure if I@m missing something? Are there more steps to take to get it working? or is there a bug in the 18.04 atlantic driver?

Also, do I now need to remove any packages to get rid of the old style “ifup / ifdown” and avoid any conflicts with netplan?

cheers

---

Edit: I tried a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 Server, and the installer has the same problem (i.e. shows 'no-link' for this NIC).

As pointed out in the comments below by @binaryanomaly, there's a bug in the kernel supplied with 18.04 for this NIC. It's fixed in kernel 4.16.6.

---

Edit: added the `/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml` file

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
#  renderer: NetworkManager
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp1s0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [192.168.0.12/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.0.2,192.168.0.1]
    enp5s0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [192.168.0.11/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.0.2,192.168.0.1]
```

Comment: I suggest that you configure the needed details in netplan and see if it works. Possibly helpful: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2371148 In this case, also only the compiled version works.

Comment: I added my `netplan` config file. It's the enp1s0 adapter. I'm not sure it's the same issue as the link you provided, as they're talking about 16.04 and 'ifconfig'. The card was working fine for me in 16.04. It's 18.04 and netplan, that I can't get it working on.

Comment: Any clues in the log? `dmesg | grep -e atl -e enp1`

Comment: For your 16.04 to 18.04 upgrade question, I just posted this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1034754/7056.  But, first you should figure out if your card is recognized by the kernel as chili has suggested.

Comment: The card seems to be recognised, as it is listed `lshw` as I mentioned in the question. It is also shown in `networkctl` and `ip link`, as well as in syslog/dmesg. The main thing I see is that I get messages when I plug/unplug the network cable in the motherboard ethernet port, but no such messages if I plug/uplug the cable in the 10g card.

Comment: Thanks for the link for cleaning up `ifupdown` though.

Comment: I have the same issue on Debian Stretch with Kernel 4.16. network card is recognized but configuration fails respectively it's not working with static or dhcp configuration. Any hints on where to further investigate?

Comment: It is a Bug in the drivers introduced with Kernel 4.16 seems to be fixed with 4.16.6: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=199177

Comment: Add: A cold boot fixes it temporarily since that causes the card to reset.

Comment: Thanks @binaryanomaly. I guess I'll wait for the kernel update to be included.

Comment: Btw. for 4.9 this worked for me:
https://github.com/Aquantia/AQtion follow the instructions in the readme https://github.com/Aquantia/AQtion/blob/master/README.txt to install the drivers.It did not work with 4.16.5 where the drivers are part of the kernel but maybe there is also a way to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to remove any packages to eliminate ifup and ifdown from your system.  These commands will only have an effect for network interfaces configured in /etc/network/interfaces.  You can even have some interfaces managed through /etc/network/interfaces and some managed through netplan on the same system.

If your interface is showing as "no carrier", this is most likely a driver issue, not a netplan issue.  You can rule out netplan by removing the interface from your yaml and attempting to configure it directly using ifconfig or ip.

Answer (score 0):

I have downloaded the driver from https://www.asus.com/Networking/XG-C100C/HelpDesk_download/ for my linux 32 bit

if you unpack the downloaded file and check asus/XG-C100C_v.5.0.1.6/LinuxDriver/Linux_2.0.15.0

## From the readme file
Building and Installation

### To manually build this driver:

1. Make sure you have all the environment to build standalone kernel module.
   On debian based systems you may do the following:

   sudo apt install linux-headers build-essential
2. Move the base driver tar file to the directory of your choice. For example,
   use /home/username/aquantia.
   Untar/unzip archive:

   cd ~/aquantia
   tar zxf Aquantia-AQtion-x.y.z.tar.gz
3. Change to the driver src directory:

   cd Aquantia-AQtion-x.y.z/
4. Compile the driver module:
   make
5. Load the module:
   sudo insmod atlantic.ko
6. Unload the driver
   sudo rmmod atlantic
7. Install the driver in the system
   make && make install

driver will be in:

```
/lib/modules/`uname -r`/aquantia/atlantic.ko
```

8. Uninstall the driver:
   make uninstall
   or run the following commands:
   sudo rm -f /lib/modules/`uname -r`/aquantia/atlantic.ko
   depmod -a `uname -r`

Answer (score -1):

Musaul had good information

in Kernel 4.15 and 14.16 you may encounter instability due to Debian kernel incompatibility  with dirty wake WOL feature in the firmware of XG-C100C.

Details in [comment 41 of kernel bug #199177](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=199177#c41)

Workaround might be included with Kernel 4.16.6 in release app june 2018, so make sure you avoid kernel between 4.15.16 and 4.16.5 with your network card.