# make netplan write resolve.conf

Tags: networking, dns, dhcp, netplan, resolv.conf

I have an Odroid C2 - a single board computer running 18.04 minimal for ARM. Originally, it was using NetworkManager + systemd-resolved to manage network connections, but since I use only Ethernet and always connected to the same network, I find it a little bit overkill, so I disable both of them and moved to Netplan. Here is my /etc/netplan/02-networkd.yaml:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: yes
```

As you can see, it is a simple DHCP configuration. Here is the result of using that config:

```
# netplan ip leases eth0
ADDRESS=10.0.0.4
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
ROUTER=10.0.0.1
SERVER_ADDRESS=10.0.0.1
T1=7200
T2=12600
LIFETIME=14400
DNS=10.0.0.1
NTP=10.0.0.1
DOMAINNAME=vault
CLIENTID=fff75f76ac00020000ab11a7b5e398b7e20ac7
```

IP address and all interface parameters set correct. The only problem I have is with DNS. I found that netplan does not update `/etc/resolve.conf` even it has all obligatory information in the leas.

Is there a way to make Netplane update/configure `/etc/resolve.conf` with DNS information it receives from DHCP without using NetworkManager or resolved?
Here is some additional info:

```
# ls -lA /etc/resolv.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 20 Apr 21 00:13 /etc/resolv.conf

# cat /etc/resolv.conf 
nameserver 10.0.0.1
search vault
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` and `cat /etc/resolv.conf` and `resolvectl` (or system-resolve --status). Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema current resolv.conf is just a regular hand-written file. It seems that this installation is missing both resolvectl and system-resolve.

Comment: Oops. A typo by me. The correct command is `systemd-resolve --status`. Give me a couple of minutes to put together a quick answer for you. Are you using VPN?

Comment: @heynnema the systemd-resolved is down, my question is how to make netplan manage resolve.conf without external services like resolved and NetworkManager.

Comment: Did you disable systemd-resolved? I just looked back and I see that you did. That and/or dnsmasq manage DNS, and /etc/resolv.conf.

Comment: Specify Network Manager as renderer for netplan config - if NM handles resolv.conf file, then that's what you want to use then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a deliberate design decision that netplan delegates management of resolver configuration to systemd-resolved.  There is no support in netplan for directly managing /etc/resolv.conf based on answers to dhcp queries.  Indeed, systemd-networkd expects to pass this information to systemd-resolved and netplan relies on this behavior.

Comment: So, I need a whole service just to maintain a single file in up to date state? Why?

Comment: The function of systemd-resolved is not to maintain /etc/resolv.conf. The function of systemd-resolved is to make it unnecessary to maintain /etc/resolv.conf, because having a resolv.conf file that changes makes name resolution unreliable across the life cycle of a system (especially for e.g. long-lived chroots, containers, etc), and also a local resolver is capable of detecting when an upstream nameserver is down and provide better behavior when compared with the in-process glibc behavior.

Comment: The user is not prevented from using netplan when systemd-resolved is absent. On my Ubuntu Server 20.04, with netplan in charge but systemd-resolved stopped, the network works normally except that /etc/resolv.conf does not get automatically maintained. Installing the resolvconf package solves that problem.

Answer (score 3):

There appears to be a lot of confusion between resolvconf, systemd-resolved and /etc/resolv.conf. Here's my 2 cents:

Ubuntu 18.04 uses systemd-resolved for name resolution. As @slangasek correctly pointed out, netplan delegates name resolution to systemd-resolved. For systemd-resolved to work properly, /etc/resolv.conf needs to point to **/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf**.

However, if you also have the resolvconf package installed on the system, the symlink /etc/resolv.conf will incorrectly point to **/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf**. This will result in name resolution failures, e.g. "Temporary failure in name resolution" error. Manual editing of /etc/resolv.conf is not recommended. The simplest resolution is to remove the resolvconf package. This will reset the symlink and all will be well (you may require a reboot or at least restart the systemd-resolved service).

Answer (score 1):

I see it a lot. Users have removed the symlink for /etc/resolv.conf, and put a hand-written file there. There's actually three different places that this symlink refers to, and I'll give you the most common one...

In `terminal`...

`cd /etc` # change directory

`sudo mv resolv.conf resolv.conf.BAK` # rename the current resolv.conf as a backup file

`sudo ln -s /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf` # recreate standard symlink

**Note**: do not manually edit /etc/resolv.conf!

Comment: systemd-resolved mast be up for the method, while I want to get rid of any 'external' services and make netplan manage resolev.conf by itself.

Comment: @e-pirate doesn't work that way... and... you use dhcp4, so you **do** rely on external services now.

Comment: DHCP client is a mast-have in that chain, as well as something to handle interface configuration on the client side, while resolved is just a mediator between dhcp and resolv.conf. In Gentoo I don't need any external service to the system, that manages network interfaces (ipupdown AFAIR), it will write data from dhcp lease to resolv.conf. I expected netplan to handle that, but it seems that netplan needs an external DNS handler like resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried static settings

A simple edit to `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and disabling `systemd-resolved.service` (as in this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/907249/719422). But that alone, while essential, does not guarantee tamper-proof resolv.conf.

Do this as SuperUser:

```
echo nameserver 8.8.8.8 > /etc/resolv.conf
chattr -e /etc/resolv.conf
chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

There actually a lot of confusion between netplan(`/etc/netplan/*.yaml`), systemd-resolved(`/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`) and `/etc/resolv.conf`.
When configuring the network with netplan, if ping pass but the domain resolve failed, check `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`, this file is usually generated from `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`. Latest ubuntu using netplan to configure network, while the older use `/etc/network/interfaces`

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on Ubuntu Server 20.04. (Unlike Desktop, Server does not use NetworkManager, so the answer to a related question for Desktop does not apply: https://askubuntu.com/a/907249/644076)

The network is configured using netplan. I disabled and stopped systemd-resolved because my router's DNS works just fine and I do not want additional complications from systemd-resolved, which I have experienced many times. Because systemd-resolved was gone, I also removed the symlink /etc/resolv.conf that pointed to /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf.

But when I restarted systemd-networkd, /etc/resolv.conf did not get created.

Thanks to inspiration from another answer (https://askubuntu.com/a/1241298/644076), I installed the resolvconf package and it just works. I did not configure anything and a symlink /etc/resolv.conf pointing to /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf with the correct content appeared.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server and Desktop) and I was looking for any solutions. I tested the [@Syncopated solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1449787/1157209) but it doesn't work in my case. I followed [this mini-guide (in Spanish)](https://kb.rolosa.com/ubuntu-problema-con-el-dns-que-esta-ignorando-algunas-busquedas/) and I got it.

You have to erase the `/etc/resolv.conf` and copy it from `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`. Similar to the way that other partners were saying but, at least in my case, with a different source.

```
$ sudo rm -f /etc/resolv.conf

$ sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```