# There is no internet connection after upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, upgrade, internet

I just followed the instuctions from this post:

[How to enable netplan on ubuntu server upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034711/how-to-enable-netplan-on-ubuntu-server-upgraded-from-16-04-to-18-04/1236327#1236327)

I added the following lines in to the config file: `/etc/netplan/config.yaml` (I had to install netplan and create the folder manually.) network: version: 2 renderer: networkd ethernets: eth0: dhcp4: true

But unfortunately I installed netplan instead of neplan.io.

After reboot, I lost every connection with my Odroid.

Server version
Netplan wasn't installed
There is no Wi-Fi hardware.

If I install netplan.io, will my odroid connect to the Internet again?

**Edit:**

dpkg -l *netplan*:
[image]

cat /etc/network/interfaces:
[image]

cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml:
[image]

sudo lshw -C network:
[image]

sudo apt install netplan.io:
[image]

After trying to install netplan.io we purged netplan.
My brother will send the odroid to me then I fight further.

Comment: Is this a desktop or server installation? If you upgraded to 18.04, netplan should have already been there. Edit your question and show me `dpkg -l *netplan*`. Are you able to make a wireless Internet connection?

Comment: Also show me `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`.

Comment: Hello, thank you for help me. The odroid is 700km away from me I will try it on the weekend, with my brother!

Comment: Is the problem on your PC, or your odroid? Is it a server or desktop installation?

Comment: I edited the quedtion, it is a server on my odroid c2

Comment: When you get access to the odroid, also show me `sudo lshw -C network`. Do you have ssh access?

Comment: @Beatr For odroid c2 your config `/etc/netplan/config.yaml` is OK. Just install netplan.io  `sudo apt update` `sudo apt install netplan.io` and check config `sudo netplan try`

Comment: So we tried to install netplan.io but there wasn't internet connection to install it.

Comment: I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

`renderer: networkd` is used in server installation.

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: true
```

For desktop netplan uses `renderer: NetworkManager` and config looks like this `/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml`

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

You can generate it (but need to remove /etc/netplan/config.yaml before)

```
sudo netplan --debug generate
sudo netplan apply
reboot
```