# Disable NetworkManager. Use netplan.io with Ubuntu 18.0.4

Tags: networking, server, network-manager

**edit**: I found it may be more efficient to reinstall the OS. I may encounter this again so I'll either create a new issue or find a way to continue this one. Also note below I created a bug report on netplan https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan/+bug/1953054

**edit**: This is interesting https://onet.vn/install-netplan-on-ubuntu.html

> By default, Netplan is disabled on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. You have to enable it manually. To enable Netplan, you have to create a file netplan in the /etc/default/ directory and add ENABLED=1 to it.

---

I have Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS. For consistency with other servers I want to use netplan.io `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yml` I've followed several postings which offer similar instructions in disabling NetworkManager and configuring / enabling netplan. This is one of them, yet it does not offer the results I'm looking for: [How to enable netplan on ubuntu server upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034711/how-to-enable-netplan-on-ubuntu-server-upgraded-from-16-04-to-18-04?noredirect=1&lq=1)

In sum, I want to completely disable NetworkManager. I want /etc/netplan to be the only means of configuring static addressing on this server.

I've disabled / enabled the appropriate services:

```
# systemctl list-unit-files | grep -i network
dbus-org.freedesktop.network1.service                            enabled
network-manager.service                                          masked
networkd-dispatcher.service                                      enabled
NetworkManager-dispatcher.service                                enabled
NetworkManager-wait-online.service                               enabled
NetworkManager.service                                           masked
systemd-networkd-wait-online.service                             enabled
systemd-networkd.service                                         enabled
```

---

And I've written a netplan configuration:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.1.30/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
```

---

However I continue to get an address from DHCP, not the netplan config:

```
2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:13:77:bd:fb:7c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.100/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp3s0
       valid_lft 1750sec preferred_lft 1750sec
    inet6 fe80::6815:1b1b:6a5a:4049/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

---

I've looked over https://netplan.io/troubleshooting/#debugging-issues-with-the-networkd-backend and I do not see files in `/run/systemd/network` In fact:

```
# ls /run/systemd/network
ls: cannot access '/run/systemd/network': No such file or directory
```

Also, in troubleshooting I've created a totally bogus `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yml` and it's still accepted:

```
FOO:
        BAR:
                FOO
```

---

```
# netplan try -d
Do you want to keep these settings?


Press ENTER before the timeout to accept the new configuration


Changes will revert in 120 seconds
Configuration accepted.

# netplan apply -d
```

What the heck is going on here?

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1091653/how-do-i-disable-network-manager-permanently

Comment: Thanks @chili555 --this is another item I followed yet the results it offers is on part of what I'm trying to accomplish. This will disable networkmanager yet it doesn't *enable* netplan. The result is the NIC is never configured on boot. No network.

Comment: Did you try: `sudo netplan generate` and: `sudo netplan apply`? Any errors or interesting clues?

Comment: Yes both of those many times. A couple of examples is in question. I'll include more recent results as I found `netplan <command> -d` is incorrect. Verbose output will only be generated by way of `netplan --debug <command>`

Comment: Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `sudo lshw -C network` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and the output of `sudo netplan generate` and `sudo netplan apply` and a screenshot of the IPv4 tab of your wired connection profile in the GUI.

Comment: I did a quick CBA and found reinstalling the system was more beneficial and efficient. I submitted a bug against netplan https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan/+bug/1953054 This shouldn't be so flimsy. I need to be done with this one it's a hell of a time sink with too many mysterious details.

Comment: @me2017 I saw your bug report. It really lacks details, and doesn't provide any real bug for anyone to solve. I'd recommend that you delete it.